# &nbsp in worwrap not working

Tags: php, html, css, php-7

I am trying to fix lengthy string's alignment issue, here is my code

```
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php $lengthyString = "This is the lengthy string ,but i miss the spacing after second line. The length and contents may vary"; ?>
    <p style="width:25%">&nbsp;Line1<br>
    &nbsp;Line2<br>
    &nbsp;<?php echo nl2br($lengthyString); ?>z<br>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But i missed spacing(&nbsp) adjustment in `$lengthyString`.Iwant to dispay the lenghty string's new lines should be uniformal with one space intend.Then i tried `wordwrap()`

```
<?php echo wordwrap($lengthyString,25,"&nbsp;<br>\n");?>
```

But this is not working ,is there any solution to include`&nbsp` in &nbsp in `wordwrap`

Expected output:

```
 Line1
 Line2
 This is the lengthy 
 string ,but i miss the 
 spacing after second 
 line. The length and 
 contents may vary
```

But I got like this

```
 Line1
 Line2
  This is the lengthy 
string ,but i miss the 
spacing after second 
line. The length and 
contents may vary
```

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work"... Have you looked at the source in the browser or just the rendering? If I understand `wordwrap` makes more sense. `nl2br` does not as I see no "new lines" in that string.

Comment: I missed spacing in next lines, Every line starts should be uniform,this is the thing i am trying

Comment: There are no newlines to convert into <br>

Comment: What is your output and what you actually want on the output.
Use list and aling accordingly for line1, line 2 etc. or just dont put inside <p> tag or simply use css for the spacing, why you want spacing using $nbsp?

Comment: Added my expected output - @webDev

Comment: remove all nbsp, look at my answer section

Comment: Get rid of the `&nbsp;`s completely and use CSS for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment above:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php $lengthyString = "This is the lengthy string ,but i miss the spacing after second line. The length and contents may vary"; ?>
    <p style="width:25%;">
        Line1<br>
        Line2<br>
        <?php echo $lengthyString; ?><br>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**And for spacing inside the `<p></p>` tag, use css.**
`&nbsp` is also a character, so you are just putting one extra character in-front.

**Updated**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    p{
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php $lengthyString = "This is the lengthy string ,but i miss the spacing after second line. The length and contents may vary"; ?>
    <p style="width:25%;">
        &nbsp;Line1<br>
        &nbsp;Line2<br>
        &nbsp;<?php echo $lengthyString; ?><br>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this small section it is okay, but in actual code I can't remove &nbsps, it will affect other portions

Comment: try to solve the issue with `white-space` property of the css. I have updated the post. see updates

Comment: I want to display the lengthy contents in multiple lines to adjust the same width to every line.